# fuzzy extracting names (stored in a vector) from a text column in R

Tags: r

I have some data which contains text and I would like to try and extract the company names from the text. The data looks like:

```
d <- data.frame(
  textColumn = c(
    "Apple CEO reports positive growth in Iphone sales",
    "Apple's quarterly results are expected to beat that of Intel's",
    "Microsoft is expected to release a new product which rivales Apple's Iphone which uses Intels processors",
    "Intel Corporation seeks to hire 5000 new staff",
    "Amazon enters a new market, the same as Intel"
  )
)
```

Data:

```
                                                                   textColumn
1                           Apple CEO reports positive growth in Iphone sales
2              Apple's quarterly results are expected to beat that of Intel's
3 Microsoft is expected to release a new product which rivales Apple's Iphone
4                              Intel Corporation seeks to hire 5000 new staff
5                               Amazon enters a new market, the same as Intel
```

In a vector I have a number of company names.

```
companyNames <- c(
  "Apple Inc",
  "Intel Corp",
  "Microsoft Corporation",
  "Amazon Company"
)
```

Data:

```
[1] "Apple Inc"             "Intel Corp"            "Microsoft Corporation" "Amazon Company"
```

The data in the text does not allow me to exactly extract the company names since the character string mostly contains the full company name `Apple Inc`, `Intel Corp` etc. but the text data refers to just the company `Apple` and `Intel` etc.

I would like to use fuzzy string extraction to try and extract the company names from the text so the expected output using this example would be:

```
c(
  "Apple",
  "Apple | Intel",
  "Microsoft | Apple | Intel",
  "Intel",
  "Amazon | Intel"
)
```

Data:

```
[1] "Apple"                     "Apple | Intel"             "Microsoft | Apple | Intel" "Intel"                     "Amazon | Intel"
```

Since `Apple` only occurs once in the first row of the text data, whereas `Apple`and `Intel` both occur in the second row (So I separate them by `|`). I am looking into the `fuzzyExtract` from the `fuzzywuzzyR` pakage [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzywuzzyR/man/FuzzExtract.html) but I cannot seem to get it working on my sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Here this uses `stringr` to clean up the company names, extract them, then collapse the names into a vector. I am sure it will require some adaptation on your part, but this should definitely get you started. Also, the `\\b` in the regex is a boundary--it protects against partial matches for the elements of `org_type`. Hope this helps!!

```
library(stringr)

# Removing the organization types  you listed (e.g., Inc)
# You may also grab the first word, I chose types because it was more explicit
# but it would reqiure checking on your part (either option will)
org_type <- c("Inc", "Corp", "Corporation", "Company")

company_clean <- str_remove_all(companyNames, str_c("\\s*\\b", org_type, "\\b", collapse = "|"))

# Extracting the company name matches from the list and pasting them together
sapply(str_extract_all(d$textColumn, str_c(company_clean, collapse = "|")), paste0, collapse = " | ")
[1] "Apple"                     "Apple | Intel"             "Microsoft | Apple | Intel" "Intel"                     "Amazon | Intel"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is an **exact** match (assuming that the company names are the same both in the 'd' data.frame and in the 'companyNames' vector),

```
    # use stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    d <- data.frame(
      textColumn = c(
        "Apple CEO reports positive growth in Iphone sales",
        "Apple's quarterly results are expected to beat that of Intel's",
        "Microsoft is expected to release a new product which rivales Apple's Iphone which uses Intels processors",
        "Intel Corporation seeks to hire 5000 new staff",
        "Amazon enters a new market, the same as Intel"
      ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    companyNames <- c(
      "Apple Inc",
      "Intel Corp",
      "Microsoft Corporation",
      "Amazon Company"
    )
    
    
    # extract the company names (without the extensions Inc, Corp etc.)
    companyNames = unlist(lapply(strsplit(companyNames, ' '), function(x) x[1]))
    
    
    # use 'gregexpr' and 'substr' to append the company names to the 'output' vector
    output = rep(NA, nrow(d))
    
    for (ROW in 1:nrow(d)) {
      
      iter_row = d[ROW, , drop = T]
      iter_vec = c()
      
      for (NAME in companyNames) {
        iter_match = gregexpr(pattern = NAME, text = iter_row)
        
        for (idx_match in 1:length(iter_match)) {
          if (iter_match[[idx_match]] != -1) {
          
            match_start_idx = iter_match[[idx_match]][1]
            match_length = attr(iter_match[[idx_match]], "match.length")
            
            iter_company = substr(iter_row, match_start_idx, match_start_idx + match_length - 1)
            iter_vec = append(iter_vec, iter_company)
          }
        }
      }
      
      output[ROW] = paste(iter_vec, collapse = ' | ')
    }
```

This gives:

```
[1] "Apple"   "Apple | Intel"   "Apple | Intel | Microsoft"   "Intel"   "Intel | Amazon"
```