# unlisting a character string and trying to find matches based on the results in the list

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I am trying to extract some names from one column. I also have a vector of company names, however the company names contain `corporate`, `corp`, `inc` etc. which make it difficult to extract the exact names. I am trying to construct a list of the company names using `list(strsplit(tolower(companyNames), '\\s+'))` and then I would like to apply the results of this list to the data frame. So if one of the words in the list appears in the data frame column `textColumn` I would like to extract this into a new dataframe column.

Data:

```
d <- data.frame(
  
  textColumn = c(
    
    "Apple CEO reports positive growth in Iphone sales",
    
    "Apple's quarterly results are expected to beat that of Intel's",
    
    "Microsoft is expected to release a new product which rivales Apple's Iphone which uses Intels processors",
    
    "Intel Corporation seeks to hire 5000 new staff",
    
    "Amazon enters a new market, the same as Intel"
    
  )
  
)


companyNames <- c(
  
  "Apple Inc",
  
  "Intel Corp",
  
  "Microsoft Corporation",
  
  "Amazon Company"
  
)
```

Comment: See also your previous question: [fuzzy extracting names (stored in a vector) from a text column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62836041/10488504).

Comment: Why is it asked twice? I am hammering this with previous one